# Animation not working in mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

I am trying to add a custom toggle icon to a mat-expansion-panel.  I would like to animate that icon on toggle of the panel.  The state does toggle and the icon rotates, but with no animation.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-overview-example.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('expandedTrigger', [
      state('true', style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' })),
      state('false', style({ transform: 'rotate(90deg)' })),
      transition('* <=> *', animate('300ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  panels = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  expanded = [false, false, false];

  toggle(index: number) {
    // This will flip the state, however the animation will not happen
    this.expanded[index] = !this.expanded[index];

    // If I use setTimeout the animation transition works
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.expanded[index] = !this.expanded[index];
    // });
  }
}
```

template:

```
<mat-accordion hideToggle="true">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let panel of panels; let i = index">
    <mat-expansion-panel #expansionPanel (opened)="toggle(i)" (closed)="toggle(i)">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{panel}}
        </mat-panel-title>
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon [@expandedTrigger]='expanded[i]'>more_vert</mat-icon></button>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

The interesting part is that if I put the state change in a timeout the animation works great.  Is there something in the expansion panel that is blocking or preventing animations while the panel is opening/closing?

I found this: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/expansion/expansion-panel-header.ts#L123-L133

However I did verify that animations are only disabled initially, and that parameter is set to false right after init before my click happens and my animation would start.

Here is a stackblitz showing the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3n3zkm

I feel like setting a timeout is a hack, any other ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I animate the icon in an expansion panel in Angular Material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096411/how-can-i-animate-the-icon-in-an-expansion-panel-in-angular-material)